# can't get Spring Security to work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security so I probably miss out on something. I have a Spring Application that starts a Jetty with a WebApplication I want to secure using Spring Security. The webapp is running and reachable, but not restricted. I've tried a lot of stuff but nothing worked so I broke it down to a minimal setup, but still no chance.
the webapp is configured by the following java configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(useDefaultFilters = false, basePackages = { "myapp.web" }, includeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(Controller.class) })
public class SpringMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    /**
     * Allow the default servlet to serve static files from the webapp root.
     */
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

and Spring Security configured here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("ADMIN")
        .authorities("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .hasAuthority("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

and some controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class SecuredController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/secure", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String secured() {
        return "you should not see this unless you provide authentication";
    }
}
```

Everything starts up all right, the log tells me, that the controller is mapped...

```
    [2014-10-01 20:21:29,538, INFO ] [main] mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping:197 - Mapped "{[/secure],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String myapp.web.SecuredController.secured()
```

...and that security is in place as well...

```
    [2014-10-01 20:21:30,298, INFO ] [main] gframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain:28 - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@352c308, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@2af616d3, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1a2e2935, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@64f857e7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@bc57b40, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@3deb2326, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7889a1ac, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7d373bcf, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5922ae77, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@7e1a1da6, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1051817b]
```

... but the `/secure` url of my controller is unconditionally reachable. What am I doing wrong?

ps. I want to avoid xml config

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate Spring Security with Spring MVC you have to use `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` annotation instead of `@EnableWebSecurity` in `SecurityConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured, I had to move the initialization of the Spring Security configuration to the root context, not the dispatcher-servlet context, and add the following line where i configure the context of my embedded Jetty:

```
    context.addFilter(new FilterHolder(new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")), "/*", EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class));
```